# JavaScript reading data into an array from a dynamic table of textfields

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dynamic, html-table

I'm dynamically creating a table using an HTML table and JavaScript Functions attatched to button clicks.  I now want to take the data and store it into multidimensional array (if possible) using another button named finished. I'm having trouble even getting started with the last method to save it into array.  I can't figure out how to retrieve the text data.

Here is my current HTML code.

```
<head>
    <title>TableTest</title>
    <script src="/javascript/func.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <form>
         <div id="Input">
                        <INPUT class="form-button" id="AddRow" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
                        <INPUT class="form-button" id="DeleteRow" type="button" value="Delete Row(s)" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
                        <INPUT class="form-button" id="Finished" type="button" value="Finished" onclick="gatherData('dataTable')" />
                    <table id="dataTable" border="1" style="width:200px" id="mytable" align="center" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="4">       
                        <th>Select</th>
                        <th>Text1</th>
                        <th>Text2</th> 
                        <th>Text3</th>
                            <tr>
                            <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
                            <td><INPUT type="text" name="text1"/></td>
                            <td><INPUT type="text" name="txt2"/></td>
                            <td><INPUT type="text" name="txt3"/></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>    
            </div>
       </form>
</body>
```

Here is my JavaScript file:

```
 function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 2) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

function gatherData(){ 


 //Tests
        var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        alert(rowCount);
        alert(row);
        alert(colCount); 
}
```

Comment: To gather data, you don't want to insert new rows, just iterate over the rows that are there (like in the *deleteRow* function) and then for each cell, collect an appropriate value (say textConent or innerText, or form control value if checked, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to keep it simple, and also jQuery clean, so to speak.

```
    var data = [];
    function gatherData() {
         var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
         for (r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++) {

             var row = table.rows[r];
             var cells = row.cells;

             for (c = 0; c < cells.length; c++) {
                 var cell = cells[c];
                 var inputElem = cell.children[0];
                 var isInput = inputElem instanceof HTMLInputElement;
                 if (!isInput)
                     return;

                 var value = inputElem.value;

                 var isCheckbox = inputElem.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox';
                 if (isCheckbox)
                     value = inputElem.checked;

                 var rowData = {};
                 rowData.inputType = inputElem.getAttribute('type');
                 rowData.inputValue = value;
                 data.push(rowData);
             }
         }
     }

     function startExec() {
         gatherData();
         for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             console.log(data[i].inputType);
             console.log(data[i].inputValue);
         }
     }
     //just wait for the dom to load, and then execute the function for testing
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startExec, false);
```

2nd Revision

```
 function getData() {

     var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
     if (table === null)
         return;

     if (table.rows[0].cells.length <= 1)
         return;

     var data = [];
     for (l = 0; l < table.rows[0].cells.length; l++) {
         data.push({
             items: [],
             name: "ColumnNumber" + l
         });
     }

     for (i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
         var cells = table.rows[i].cells;
         for (c = 0; c < cells.length; c++) {
             var inputElem = cells[c].children[0];
             data[c].items.push({
                 inputType: inputElem.getAttribute('type'),
                 inputValue: inputElem.value
             });
         }
     }
     printData(data);
 }

 function printData(data) {
     for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         for (k = 0; k < data[i].items.length; k++) {
             console.log(data[i].items[k].inputValue);
         }
     }
 }

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getData(), false);
```

It's great that you're starting off and doing the table manipulation yourself, and I would recommend continuing that, if you want to peak into a bigger codebase I would recommend checking out [jTable's](https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/blob/master/lib/jquery.jtable.js). Even though it's a jQuery plugin, you'll still be able to learn something from looking at the code structure for handling all the logic surrounding building a table according to a dataset and adding records etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have been planning to look at jTable, but I wanted to gain a better understanding of this first.  I have another question for you.  I'm using the check boxes just to delete rows if the check box is selected, I don't want to store the data inside them.  How could I pass over these values?? Also would it be possible to store the data into separate arrays? For example tex1Column[], text2Column[], text3Column[], or allData[text1Column][text2Column][text3Column].  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: so you'd like to store all the text of one column in an array, so say you have three rows, with these values in the cells, 1 2 3, 1 2 3, 1 2 3. then you'd like to have arrays text1column[1,1,1] and text2column[2,2,2] and so on ?

Comment: Ok, added another revision, with your request, it would be good to just add a case statement to treat input tags per type.

Answer (score 2):

I reworked TameBadger's answer to build the array by row instead of by column.  I also added a check to see if the given cell has a value before referencing it.  In my case, not all cells have values.

```
 var table = document.getElementById('mainTable');

 if (table === null)
     return;

 if (table.rows[0].cells.length <= 1)
     return;

 var tblData = [];

 //Put a RowNumber name and values placeholder for the number of rows we have.
 for (r = 0; r < table.rows.length; r++) 
 {
     //Debug
     //console.log(" row: ", r);     

     tblData.push({
         name: "RowNumber" + r,
         items: []
     });

     //Get the cells for this row.
     var cells = table.rows[r].cells;

     //Loop through each column for this row and push the value...
     for (c = 0; c < cells.length; c++) 
     {
         var inputElem = cells[c].children[0];
         var tmpInputElem;

         if (inputElem == null)
         {
            tmpInputElem = "";
         }
         else
         {
            tmpInputElem = inputElem.value           
         }

         //Debug
         //console.log(" row-cel: ", r, "-", c, " ", inputElem);

         tblData[r].items.push(
         {
             //Comment out the type for now...
             //inputType: inputElem.getAttribute('type'),
             inputValue: tmpInputElem
         });
     }
 }

 //Debug
 //printData(tblData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/m3h2N/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Finished').click(function(){
        var my_arr=[];

        $('td').each(function(){

            if ($(this).children().is(':checkbox') )
            {
                if($(this).children().prop('checked'))
                {                                      
                    my_arr.push($(this).children().val());
                }               
            }else{           
                my_arr.push($(this).children().val());
            }
        })
        console.log(my_arr);
    })


})
```

Comment: Sorry this is the JQuery version!